# How to convert a Field class instance to Generic Instance

Tags: java, generics, reflection

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calculation {
    static double pm10,pm2dot5,no2,o3,co,so2,nh3,pb;
    static HashMap<String, Double> concentration;
    static HashMap<String, Double> subIndex;
    static Scanner sc ;
    public static HashMap<Integer, Integer> _pm10,_pm2dot5,_no2,_o3,_so2,_nh3;
    public static HashMap<Integer, Double> _co,_pb;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        indexCalculation();
    }
    static void indexCalculation () throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException
    {
        Iterator<String> gases = concentration.keySet().iterator();
        while(gases.hasNext())
        {
            String gas = gases.next();
            double value = concentration.get(gas);
            String str = "_"+gas;//this will create string instance like _so2,_nh3 etc..
            Class obj = calculation.class;
            Field field = obj.getField(str);
            Iterator<Integer> breakpoint = field.keySet().iterator();//unable to do..
        }
    }
}
```

- How to convert field instance to HashMap instance, so than I can call
  `keySet()` method on it.
- Or their any other to call an instance at run time.

Comment: Trying to get a field named like *"_"+gas* will always throw a _NoSuchFieldException_ as your fields have other names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get` method of field class to get the value. Here's what the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get(java.lang.Object)) says:

> Returns the value of the field represented by this Field, on the
>   specified object. The value is automatically wrapped in an object if
>   it has a primitive type.

The code will look like this:

```
static void indexCalculation () throws Exception{
    concentration = new HashMap<>(); //only for testing, remove this
    concentration.put("so2", 10d); //only for testing, remove this
    Iterator<String> gases = concentration.keySet().iterator();
    while(gases.hasNext())
    {
        String gas = gases.next();
        double value = concentration.get(gas);
        String str = "_"+gas;//this will create string instance like _so2,_nh3 etc..
        Class obj = calculation.class;
        Field field = obj.getField(str);
        Class<?> type = field.getType();
        if(type == HashMap.class){
            HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = (HashMap<Integer, Integer>) field.get(calculation.class);
            System.out.println(map);
        }
    }
}
```

Once you get the `Map`, you can call any method of `Map` interface (e.g. `keySet()`, `get()` etc).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `get(obj)` and cast the result to the correct class. `Field` instances are just references to the field. Calling `get` requires an object on which to evaluate the field's value, see [the field class docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html).